# JQuery tabs opacity transition

Tags: jquery, animation, tabs, opacity

```
$("#tabs-left").tabs({opacity:'toggle', duration:'normal'});
```

This is what I have at the moment. I'm very new to JQuery and it doesn't seem to be working. As far as I know it should be working.

Just wondering if I haven't crossed a T or dotted an i somewhere.

P.s. Can't give example due to work sorry.

Comment: Can't give answer due to no example sorry.

Comment: you don't have to share real-time example @samhats, actually you SHOULD come up with a sample XML that kind of matches your requirement! use `foo-bar` kind of elements.. Stackoverflow rule says `don't write realtime code`  and I say **Nobody's here to steel your code** :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/qzjaQ/1/

```
$(function() {
 $("#tabs-left").tabs({
     show: {
         opacity:'toggle',
         duration:'normal'
     }
 });

 // getter
 var show = $(".selector").tabs("option", "show");

 // setter
 $(".selector").tabs("option", "show", {
     opacity:'toggle',
     duration: 'normal'
 });
});​
```

See [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-show) for explanations..